# Connect an external monitor to notebook via HDMI - doesn't work - black screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 330 with two graphic cards, intel and nvidia.
I connected the hdmi to an external monitor, the monitor gets detected. For a moment the monitor resumes from safe mode (straight after connection), then it says that there is no signal and then it turns back into safe mode.

In Ubuntu Settings -> Display, I tried all the options, Join displays, mirror, and single display (to only use the external monitor).
None of them works.

In Join displays and in Single Displaythe model of the monitor appears. So it seems well detected.

Here is the output xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95 +
   1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00    50.00  
   720x576i      50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

When I have the HDMI unplugged (strange) I see this in journalctl, a plenty of such messages being logged all the time:

```
wrz 30 23:15:42 myname-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1569878142.636:7225580): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/2" pid=9231 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
wrz 30 23:15:42 myname-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1569878142.636:7225581): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/2" pid=9231 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
wrz 30 23:15:42 myname-lenovo kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1569878142.636:7225582): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/2" pid=9231 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
wrz 30 23:15:42 myname-lenovo audit[9231]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/2" pid=9231 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
wrz 30 23:15:42 myname-lenovo audit[9231]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/2" pid=9231 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
wrz 30 23:15:42 myname-lenovo audit[9231]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/2" pid=9231 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
wrz 30 23:15:42 myname-lenovo audit[9231]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/2" pid=9231 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

When I plugin in the HDMI I get this:

```
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1955
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.39  1920 1968 2000 2104  1080 1083 1089 1120 +hsync -vsync (67.2 kHz eP)
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1955
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.39  1920 1968 2000 2104  1080 1083 1089 1120 +hsync -vsync (67.2 kHz eP)
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1955
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.39  1920 1968 2000 2104  1080 1083 1089 1120 +hsync -vsync (67.2 kHz eP)
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1955
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.39  1920 1968 2000 2104  1080 1083 1089 1120 +hsync -vsync (67.2 kHz eP)
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1955
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.39  1920 1968 2000 2104  1080 1083 1089 1120 +hsync -vsync (67.2 kHz eP)
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1955
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.39  1920 1968 2000 2104  1080 1083 1089 1120 +hsync -vsync (67.2 kHz eP)
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
wrz 30 23:17:59 myname-lenovo gsd-color[1202]: no xrandr-Dell Inc.-DELL U2413-84K963B4A96L device found: Failed to find output xrandr-Dell Inc.-DELL U2413-84K963B4A96L
wrz 30 23:18:00 myname-lenovo audit[9231]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/2" pid=9231 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

And when I run `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --same-as eDP-1` I get:
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II)

```
modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1955
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.39  1920 1968 2000 2104  1080 1083 1089 1120 +hsync -vsync (67.2 kHz eP)
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1955
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.39  1920 1968 2000 2104  1080 1083 1089 1120 +hsync -vsync (67.2 kHz eP)
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1423]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
wrz 30 23:19:27 myname-lenovo gnome-control-c[13318]: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Logical monitors not adjecent
wrz 30 23:19:28 myname-lenovo gnome-control-c[13318]: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Logical monitors not adjecent
```

What else can I try?

Comment: have you tried connecting it acutally *using* xrandr? (not just looking at the output)

Comment: I don't think so. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you check the UEFI Setings/BIOS for Nvidia settings.  My Thinkpad requires that Nvidia be enabled to use the second monitor.

Comment: @ubfan1 unfortunately in my bios there are no such options. Just an option about switchable graphics, which was already enabled...

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the `xrandr` tool to connect. The command I tend to use is as follows

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --left-of eDP1
```

`--output`: This tells `xrandr` that you want to modify one (or multiple should you please) outputs

`HDMI1`: this is the output you want to modify, which can be obtained from `xrandr`'s dump. (Though I think for most use cases `HDMI1` should be correct [can someone confirm this?])

`--auto`: automatically sets a few settings? (i dont quite remember what this one does)

`--left-of`: sets the position or orientation of the second screen, you can pass in `--left-of`, `--right-of`, `--above`, `--below`, and `--same-as`

`eDP1`: the name of the default screen.

Comment: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --sameas eDP-1` When I first run this command, the main screen turns off for half second. But in the external monitor nothing happens.
If I repeat, nothing happens at all. If I unplug and plugin in the hdmi cable once again, and I re-run the command, the screen once again goes black of a moment, but still nothing happens. Also tried with `--left-of`

Comment: @Pikk what do the logs say? Do both screens go back? Try running `journalctl -f` on the and check the output (assuming you have a screen that doesn't turn balack"

Comment: The external monitor is all the time black. Sometimes it gives some light when I run the command, but still being black. The lenovo goes black for few seconds when I run the command, then back to normality. I updated the original question with some logs.

Comment: does `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --same-as eDP-1` work?

Comment: I copied and pasted this command, and still the same... I doesn't work

Comment: it is probably a hardware issue. Also on Windows there is the same problem. Brand new notebook :( I called Lenovo and they said to send it to them for repair. I can do that probably in December